# No route to host. How to SSH from guest machine in virtualbox to host machine by bridged adapter?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ssh

Sorry for the mistakes I've made.

I'm trying to connect through ssh to my host machine (Ubuntu 13.10) from guest machine (Ubuntu Server 13.10) which has bridged adapter.
Vice versa everything ok - I connect to guest just by typing `ssh user@dhcp-ip`, but when I try to connect conversely I get the following:

`connect to host 192.168.0.x port 22: No route to host`.

IP on host machine is taken from the `ifconfig` from eth0.

Recently, I've checked up that port 22 is listened by ssh server daemon on the host machine. What I do wrong?

Comment: What port is SSH listening to on the host/guest?

Comment: I find out that by default Ubuntu Desktop doesn't have ssh-server(!), but Ubuntu Server has!) Now I try to install ssh-server and test it again. Thank you for your question it's half of the answer:)

Comment: Yeah if that was the case it will resolve your issue. You need an SSH-server for SSH, and this is not installed per default on a desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem is in ssh-server on host machine (because of wrong configuration there is no connection). I didn't solve the problem - I just move to Docker.

Comment: Can you share the details of the configuration problem that was fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately, I even don't remember I solved it or not (probably not, because as long as I remember - correct configuration didn't help me). But at the moment I don't use Virtualbox at all, I move to docker.